# cp overwriting without overwriting hardlinks to destination

Tags: cp, mv, hard-link, ln

Say I have the following setup :

```
$ cat fileA
textA
$ cat fileB
textB
$ ln fileA myLink
$ cat myLink # as expected
textA
```

I do not understand the following behaviour :

```
$ cp fileB fileA
$ cat myLink # expected ?
textB
```

I would have expected this outcome if I had written `ln -s fileA myLink` instead, but not here.

I would have expected `cp` in overwriting mode to do the following :

1. Copy the content of `fileB` somewhere on the hard drive
2. Link `fileA` to that hard drive address

but instead, I infer it does the following :

1. Follow the link `fileA`
2. Copy the content of `fileB` at that address

The same does not seem to go for `mv`, with whick it works as I expected.

My questions :

1. Is this explained somewhere that I have missed in `man cp` or `man mv` or `man ln` ?
2. Is this behaviour just a coincidence, *(say if `fileB` is not much greater in size than `fileA`)*, or can it be reliably used as a feature ?
3. Does this not defeat the idea of hard links ?
4. Is there some way to modify the line `cp fileB fileA` so that the next `cat myLink` still shows `textA` ?

Comment: for question 4. , one can do `rm fileA && cp fileB fileA` to preserve `myLink` from the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "following the link" with hardlinks - creating a hardlinks simply gives several different names to the same file (at low level, files are actually integer numbers - "inodes", and they have names just for user convenience)- there is no "original" and "copy" - they are the same. So it is completly the same  which of the hardlinks you open and write to, they are all the same.

So `cp` by defaults opens one the files and writes to it, thus changing the file (and hence all the names it has). So yes, it is expected. Now, if you (instead of rewriting) first removed one of the names (thus reducing link count) and then recreated new file with the same name as you had, you would end up with two different files. That is what `cp --remove-destination` would do.

**1** basics are documented at  `link(2)` pointed to by `ln(1)`

**2** yes it is normal behaviour and not a fluke. But see above remark about `cp --remove-destination`

**3** no, not really. Hardlinks are simply several names for same file. What you seem to want are COW (copy-on-write) links, which only exist is special filesystems

**4** yes, `cp --remove-destination fileB fileA`

Comment: Thank you. Basically what I expected was that `cp` worked as `cp --remove-destination`. I stand corrected. Sorry for the clumsy wording.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.  `ln fileA myLink` creates a *hard link*, that is, fileA and myLink are two names for the same disk file.

Use `ls -il` to display *inode* numbers, and you will see that you have only two distinct files created at the end of your example.

In addition to the man pages you referenced, you might also want to read [`man 2 link`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) for more detail on the underlying system call.

---

> I infer that cp not only overwrites the link of fileA to a link to a newly created copy of fileB, but actually follows the link of fileA and writes a copy of fileB there ?

You are misinterpreting what a *link* is.  `cp` does not 'follow the link of fileA' any more than it follows the link of myLink.  Both directory entries are linked to the same inode.  Consider that when you `rm` a file, the underlying system call is named [`unlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html).

Comment: Thank you. I now realize that my question is more about `cp` than about `ln`.